# Why is it invalid syntax when i use a variable \n and then * 3 in python?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdIwx.png)
my code gives an error, even without the " "
onecompiler runs on 2.8 i believe

I wanted it to say:
dave
dave
dave
dave
dave

I am still a beginner and am following a codechamp video, I am at like 3:05

Comment: 2.8 doesn't make sense as a "compiler". You could have python 2.7 or 3.x so I have no idea what 2.8 refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this output

```
dave
dave
dave
```

You need to wirte this

```
print((name + "\n") * 3)
```

Instead of this

```
print(name "\n" * 3)
```

You get an error because of `name "\n"`. If you want to concatenate two strings you should use `+`.

Comment: @Amolgorithm. I don't think this makes any difference. OP clearly is learning Python and the main reason he asked question is because of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `print((name + "\n") * 3)`, another option is to use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings), like this:

```
print(f"{name}\n" * 3)
```